# How to use NSPredicate to filter an array stored in CoreData?

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate

I have a 'tags' array stored in CoreData (type 'Transformable') as an Array.
I am making a request to CoreData to retrieve tags based on a searchText (string) input.

How can I use NSPredicate to filter the tags array based on the searchText?

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: Constants.Trip)

if(searchText != nil && searchText != "") {
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY %@ in tags", searchText!)
}

request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that. Check this answer [core data array of string filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37294459/core-data-array-of-string-filter)

You might consider to have an entity for tags, or join the array of tags and have it as a whole string in your current entity, thus having the tags property as type String. For the last approach, you could search with the predicate below.

```
 NSPredicate(format: "tags CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText)
```

The [cd] expression is to specify case and diacritic insensitivity respectively.
You can get know more about the Core Data operations [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html).

I got some basic operators from the documentation and put them below:

BEGINSWITH
The left-hand expression begins with the right-hand expression.

CONTAINS
The left-hand expression contains the right-hand expression.

ENDSWITH
The left-hand expression ends with the right-hand expression.

LIKE
The left hand expression equals the right-hand expression: ? and * are allowed as wildcard characters, where ? matches 1 character and * matches 0 or more characters.

Comment: I tried this previously & keep getting an 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS' error when the fetch request is made. (The fetch works fine without a predicate). I've tripled checked the entity name & property name, so not sure why this is happening...

Comment: Now I got your question. I updated the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for clarifying this! I was going insane.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write predicate  and set as a part of request like this ...

```
func getEntitiesWithName(_ entityName:String, sortKey:String?, predicate: NSPredicate?, ascending:Bool, context:NSManagedObjectContext) -> [NSManagedObject] {

    var results:[NSManagedObject] = [NSManagedObject]()

    context.performAndWait { () -> Void in

        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>()
        request.entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: entityName, in: context)

        if let fetchPredicate = predicate {
            request.predicate = fetchPredicate
        }

        if let key = sortKey {

            let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: key, ascending: ascending, selector: #selector(NSString.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(_:)))
            request.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor];
        }

        results = (try! context.fetch(request)) as! [NSManagedObject]
    }

    return results
}
```

And you can set predicate like this

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "isActive == %@", NSNumber(value: true as Bool))
```